# Identify unique record for insert without unique identifier in raw data

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database of item sales, but all that is present is the date/time of the sale, and the price. For example:

| item | date_time | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red shirt | 7/19/22 18:48 | 20 |
| blue shirt | 7/19/22 18:45 | 15 |
| shoes | 7/19/22 18:43 | 29.99 |

Now, I want to load that data into a MySQL DB, but am having trouble trying to figure out how to do so without a unique saleID identifier in the raw data I am pulling. For example, there could be two red shirts that sell at 18:48 on 7/19/22 and I want to insert them both, since they are not duplicate sales. However, I do not want to insert a duplicate sale. The only way I thought to attack this was to add a unique identifier column that somehow summarizes all of the sales before it. An example of what I'm thinking is below.

SQL Table

| id | item | date_time | price | sales_before |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red shirt | 7/19/22 18:48 | 20 |  |
| 2 | red shirt | 7/19/22 18:52 | 16 | 1 |
| 3 | red shirt | 7/19/22 18:53 | 18 | 1,2 |

So if my next data pull gets 3 red shirt sales, I'll know that the third sale is a duplicate since I only have 3 in my table. However, if I get 4 red shirt sales, I'll know that the last one is a new sale, even if its time is at 7/19/22 18:53. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how do you decide when a row is a duplicate or a new sale. What's the criteria to differentiate?

Comment: @TheImpaler I've got a list of all of the sales, so I can visually see when there are multiple sales of the same item, at the same price, at the same time. However, I'm trying to figure out the logic in inserting the legitimate, non-duplicate sales into a table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option here might be to add the `id` column as an auto increment column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE sales ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

After executing the above, every record in the table should have a unique `id` value.  In addition, each new record which gets added should also be given a new `id` value.

Comment: The issue is not the unique records in the table, it's that there is no unique ID in the raw sales that I'm pulling and trying to insert. I'm not sure how adding an auto increment column will help determine if a record is new or a duplicate

Comment: An auto increment column would at least break the tie between 2 or more records which were otherwise identical.